# Where I can find an ipa file containing private API?

Tags: ipa, iphone-privateapi

I want to have an ipa file generated with Private API to test whether private-api identifying tool works or not. Could someone tell me how I can find such file? Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking, this question isn't good fit for stack overflow. Yes, it's kind-of related to software development, but it's out there (it's more related to a look usage than to a real software development problem). I would recommend to read stack overflow faq.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and reminder, Victor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to build one on your own.

Just put this code in .h or top of .m file:

```
@interface UIDevice()
    -(float)_backlightLevel;
@end
```

And in the code call:

```
float a = [[UIDevice currentDevice] _backlightLevel];
NSLog(@"Backlight level %f", a);
```

Now, you are using private API.